# The ring $\mathbb{Q}[x]/<(x-1)^2>$ is not isomorphic to the ring $\mathbb{Q}[x]/<(x^2-1)>$

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

The ideals containing $<(x-1)^2>$ are $<(x-1)>$ and $<(x-1)^2$. The ideals containing $<(x^2-1)>$ are $<(x^2-1)>$, $<(x-1)>$, and $<(x+1)>$. By the correspondence theorem, there are $2$ proper ideals of $\mathbb{Q}[x]/<(x^2-1)>$ and $1$ proper ideal of $\mathbb{Q}[x]/<(x-1)^2>$; hence, these two rings are not isomorphic.

Does my proof look good? Any issues. Thanks!

Comment: A typographical point -- your presentation will look better if you use \langle and \rangle rather than < and >.  Your proof seems correct.  Depending on how much background you've already developed, you might want to prove (rather than just state) that the ideals you've identified are the only ideals containing $\langle (x-1)^2 \rangle$ and $\langle (x^2-1) \rangle$, respectively.  Another proof, by the way, is to show that only one of the quotient rings has a non-zero element $p$ satisfying $p^2=0$.

Comment: @RobertShore Thank you, I will take note of the other proof since I'm studying for a qual.

Comment: As an additional hint to @RobertShore 's answer, a good place to start in your analysis of ideals of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ containing a given ideal is to note that because $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field, the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is a principal ideal domain.